# Using Identity Claims to control MVC Menus, Controller Authorisation, and Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, claims

**I've been looking for ways to implement authorisation in MVC (after years using Active Directory for everything!) using the latest Identity Claims functionality. I've posted a suggestion below but my question is, does anyone have any better ideas? Are there more "standard" ways of achieving this?**

Back in the day, Forms Authentication Users and Roles was the way of controlling authentication and authorisation in web applications. Often a small number of roles were used corresponding to business roles (e.g. Administrator, Manager, Worker). It was possible (and still is) to use Roles at a higher level of granularity, say creating a role using a string for each MVC [controller] + [action]. This does require extra tables to manage the business roles at a lower level of granularity, but it can be done quite simply.

With the advent of "Claims" in the latest ASP.NET Identity, I think a better authorisation implementation is possible. There are a number of ways in which this can be done, I'm suggesting a reasonably minimal one below.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Controller base class and override the OnActionExecuting method. I saved some claims for a user in the database with a Claim Type of the controller name and a Claim Value of either "Read", "Edit", "Create", "Delete", which are the typical claims a user has on a controller. I've added these claims to the view bag for use in the view.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // get user claims
            var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;

            if (user != null)
            {
                // Get all user claims on this controller. In this controler base class, [this] still gets the descendant instance type, hence name
                List<Claim> claims = user.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == this.GetType().Name).ToList();

                // set Viewbag with default authorisations on this controller
                ViewBag.ClaimRead = claims.Any(c => c.Value == "Read");
                ViewBag.ClaimEdit = claims.Any(c => c.Value == "Edit");
                ViewBag.ClaimCreate = claims.Any(c => c.Value == "Create");
                ViewBag.ClaimDelete = claims.Any(c => c.Value == "Delete");
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

Controller actions use a custom authorisation to protect them

```
[ClaimsAuthorize("ApplianceTypesController", "Create")]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

In the Razor view, add controls only when authorised

```
<p>
    @if (ViewBag.ClaimCreate)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    }
</p>
```

Rather than put additional authorisation into Controllers and elsewhere, I've put it into the custom authorisation class

```
public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string claimType;
    private string claimValue;

    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string type, string value = "")
    {
        this.ClaimType = type;
        this.ClaimValue = value;
    }

    public string ClaimType { get => claimType; protected set => claimType = value; }

    public string ClaimValue { get => claimValue; protected set => claimValue = value; }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User != null)
        {
            var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;

            if (user != null && user.HasClaim(ClaimType, ClaimValue))
            {
                filterContext.Result = null;
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
            else
            {
                // we don't use 401 as this will cause a login loop :  base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "You are forbidden to access this resource");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than use a standard Site-Map, I have a table of menu items based around the Claim Types (ignoring any values). I make the assumption that any claim to a controller and its pages will show the menu item to get there. This lives in a partial view as part of the menu

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(m => m.ParentId == null).OrderBy(m => m.SequenceNumber))
{
    @Html.ActionLink(item.DisplayText, item.ActionName, item.ControllerName, null, new { @class = "nav-item nav-link active" })
}
```